# Removing last baseboard heater on (I believe) single pipe/monoflo system

Tags: water-circulating-heating

I live in a duplex, I am replacing the floors in my tenant's unit adding radiant heat.

There are two baseboards in the living room, each off different piping, they do not connect no loops are formed.

The one I want to remove is the last one in the string that goes through the other bed rooms.

Am I able to just remove the baseboard and piping and cap the end to it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure of the piping system that you have.

If you have a single pipe or mono flow system like the example below, you can cap off the supply and return pipes to/from the baseboard heater, making sure that the loop is not dead-headed.

**Single pipe or mono flow system:**
[image: single pipe or mono flow system]

However, if you have a series circuit, like the example below (note that the loop pipe can be located below the floor, and offset up/down at the baseboard) then capping the supply and return lines will dead-head the loop. In this case, you can remove the baseboard and install a straight pipe to reconnect the loop, insulate the pipe and box it in.

**Series circuit system:**
[image]

You can also have a hybrid system that could use a mix of the two systems.

Comment: Oh thank you very much, illustrators are awesome. From what it looks like (from the crawlspace) it is a series circuit system. What do you mean by dead-head?

Comment: @ryanh, Dead-heading a pump is when you break the loop and prevent the water from circulating back to the pump's inlet.